# Is it possible to have a "stacking-cloud" div layout?

Tags: html, stack, cloud, gravity, inverse

I am trying to create the following layout with divs (every of them have a random fixed width and height):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJADe.png

So I was trying with the float parameter but it always ends up with the layout divided according to the highest height of a div:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6U96.png

**Does someone know how to do this special layout without using absolute positioning**, in order to keep the full liquid feature intact? It looks like a "div-cloud" or a "box2d-inversed-gravity-stack"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible with CSS alone, but I could be wrong. You could use JavaScript to do it though.

I found a library called [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which looks like it does what you want. I haven't tried it but it might be worth looking into.